# How can i change image upload derivative path?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How are you?
I used image module in core package.
image upload path: sites/default/files/field/image/1.png
image derivative path: sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/1.png?itok=CY_qUJaA
how can i change image derivative path to other?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path explicitly on field's configuration page

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but i don't know well. where is field's configuration page?

Comment: You added the field using CCK like interface, right? Go to that interface again and click on 'configure' link against the field.

Comment: Thank you. My drupal website works well on localhost, but it doesn't work on live server about uploading derivative image. The image (1.png) has uploaded in the directory(sites/default/files/field/image), but i can't see the derivative image in directory path(sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image). so i wanted to change image derivative path. please help me. i have wasted lots of days. hope your reply.